# Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' array

Tags: php, wordpress, plugins

One of my wordpress plugins is not working fine , i get this error

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ':', expecting ';' or.... line 159

```
private static function getRepositories(): array    /*line 159*/
{
    return [
        new WP_AccessTokenRepository(),
        new WP_RefreshTokenRepository(),
        new WP_ImportPropertyRepository(),
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Your server's php version in lower than 7.2, therefore the abovementioned syntax is invalid. 
To fix it, simply update your php in the server.

EDIT: 
If you are the author of this plugin, as @Ken Y-N said in the comments, you should make the code compatible with php5, as that is the officially supported minimum php version for wordpress

Comment: Or remove the `:array` bit, especially if it is a plugin the OP plans to distribute, as WordPress only requires 5.x or more, IIRC.

Comment: I have update it to 7.1 version , but then i am getting this error "Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002]" line 359 ---  and this is line 359 :    'db' => new PDO('mysql:host=' . $wpdb->dbhost . ';dbname=' . $wpdb->dbname, $wpdb->dbuser, $wpdb->dbpassword),

Comment: i assumed that its a third party plugin here. will update the answer accordingly @KenY-N

Comment: @c63Coupe the wordpress plugin cannot connect to your mysql server. Check if the server is properly configured, accessible and that all the connection params are valid

Comment: Everything works fine , just the plugin make problems if i activate it.

Comment: without knowing the plugin, its really hard to say more. Maybe plugin cannot reach the db connection parameters or uses a different connector than the remaining plugins?